# How do I enable wireless on HP Pavilion dm1?

Tags: 11.10, wireless, network-manager, hp

My wireless network is physically enabled and the "enable wireless" appears properly on the top menu, however checking it doesn't seem to have any affect. Anyone came across this problem? I have a new HP Pavilion dm1-4000, installed Ubuntu 11.10 yesterday.

The wireless worked fine yesterday, today I've got nothing. It also seems to have problems with the wired connection, however I have no idea if it's related.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information?

Answer (score 1):

in terminal type:

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

dv2000 wireless button has some detailed erratic issue , i use this command always works 
cheers

Answer (score -2):

Ndiswrapper, good tool. You take a windows driver of wifi adapter, and install on Ubuntu with this tool

Comment: This doesn't really explain how to install or use ndiswrapper. Plus, it doesn't really make sense to suggest ndiswrapper unless there is no native driver that works well. I recommend expanding this answer to explain in detail how to use ndiswrapper, and also, if possible, to justify the idea that it's the best approach for this particular OP's computer.